# Why Isn't the Value of 0 Being Passed in the foreach Loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Trying to test my code before adding it to Production, but why is the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop only passing 3 values to `$strokes` and not all 4 `$_POST` array values. One of them being `0`.

**Code:** https://ideone.com/qBO4rx

```
$_POST = array("h1" => 1, "h2" => 2, "h3" => 3, "h4" => 0);
$strokes = array();

$strokes_keys = array('h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4');

    foreach ($strokes_keys as $stroke) {
      if ($_POST[$stroke]) {
          array_push($strokes, $_POST[$stroke]);
        }
    }

    $counts = count($strokes);

    var_dump($strokes);
    var_dump($counts);
```

**Results:**

```
Success time: 0.04 memory: 52480 signal:0
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
int(3)
```

Comment: Try: if ($_POST[$stroke] !== null)

Comment: Why will you name an array as $_POST? WHY???

Comment: @khandelwaldeval I'm just replicating client-side `POST`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `array_push($strokes, $_POST[$stroke]);` does not execute for last item, because zero equals to `false`. Maybe you should try:

```
if (isset($_POST[$stroke])) {
     array_push($strokes, $_POST[$stroke]);
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, `isset` is so not intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `if ($_POST[$stroke])` evaluates to `false` if $_POST['stroke'] is zero (or an empty string, `null`, `false`).

Here you can find more information about how various types are compared:
http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Perhaps you should write your condition to:

`if ($_POST[$stroke] > 0)`